# Complex list for risk assessment

Tags: list

I am trying to make a list for a flight operations operational risk assessment project. Each "trip" is made up of a variable number of "legs." Each leg has a "departure" and a "destination" airport as well as an "enroute" portion. For each departure, destination, and enroute portion of a leg there are a variety of risks, i.e. runway type, length; weather, terrain, etc. Here's how I picture it in my mind

```
                             RUNWAY  CREW-EXPERIENCE  WEATHER  FATIGUE, ETC, ETC. TOTAL

      DEPARTURE   KJFK         1           2            0        0      0     0     3
LEG1 
      DESTINATION KATL         0            1           1        1      0     0     3

      DEPARTURE   KATL         0            0           1        1      0     0     2
LEG 2 
      DESTINATION KMIA         0            0           0        1     0     0      1 

LEG 3, 4, 5 and so on...
```

Does anyone know if this kind of list is possible in SharePoint or Info Path and how to begin to go about creating it?

Thanks,

Tom McDonald

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar in InfoPath for a form library for travel requests. You just need to create a repeating table that is comprised of all the fields in leg 1 above. Then each additional leg, the user can add a new row giving them new sets of departure and destination fields.

Comment: Is there a use a repeating list to generate a departure and destination row for each subsequent leg while keeping each row tied to a specific leg? Thanks for the help!

Comment: My previous comment should read "Is there a way to use a repeating list to generate a departure and destination for each subsequent leg while keeping each row tied to a specific leg?"

Comment: Each row of the repeating table would be for each leg. So user adds Leg 1, then hits the add another row button and adds Leg 2, so on and so forth until they are back home.

Comment: That's where I get hung up - each "Leg" has two rows, one for a departure and one for a destination. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yes, just include all those fields in the row and then reorganize the display so it appears as 2.